# Uniqueness in XSD or DTD with namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, dtd

I need to create some rules in the .xsd or the .dtd for these cases:

1. The name of the songs can't be repeated. (I am not sure if I did it
   in my code,  please check)
2. the elements comments and genre can be
   optional, the rest of them are required. (I am not sure if I did it
   in my code, please check)
3. There are just 3 types of values for the
   element genre, pop, rock and jazz. (I am sure I did it in my code,
   please check)

This is my code, but I am getting this errors from http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ in the XML document:

```
7:  60  Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "catalog".
7:  60  Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "catalog".
7:  60  Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" must be declared for element type "catalog".
```

**catalog.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog 
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLoc ation="http://www.w3schools.com catalog.xsd">

<song>
    <name2>Bed of Roses</name2>
    <artist>Bon Jovi</artist>
    <album>Cross Road</album>
    <year>1995</year>
    <genre>rock</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/bon jovi</path>
</song>
<song>
    <name2>Fly Away from here</name2>
    <artist>Aerosmith</artist>
    <album>Just Push Play</album>
    <year>2001</year>
    <genre>rock</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/aerosmith</path>
</song>
<song>
    <name2>Jossie</name2>
    <artist>Blink 182</artist>
    <album>Blink 182</album>
    <year>2001</year>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/blink 182</path>
</song>
<song>
    <name2>Want you bad</name2>
    <artist>The Offspring</artist>
    <album>Conspiracy of One</album>
    <year>2000</year>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/the offspring</path>
</song>
<song>
    <name2>The One that you love</name2>
    <artist>Air Supply</artist>
    <album>The One that you love</album>
    <year>1981</year>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/air supply</path>
</song>

</catalog>
```

**catalog.DTD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT catalog (song+)>
<!ELEMENT song (name2,artist,album,year,genre,comments,path)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name2 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT artist (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT album (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT comments (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT path (#PCDATA)>
```

**catalog.XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="catalog">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="song" maxOccurs="5">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="name2" minOccurs="1"type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="artist" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="album" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="year" minOccurs="1" type="xs:integer"/>
                  <xs:element name="genre" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="pop"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="rock"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="jazz"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:element>                     
                <xs:element name="comments" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="path" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The name of the songs cant be repeated. (I am not sure if I did it
>      in my code,  please check)

Yes, because `maxOccurs` defaults to `1`.  (The default values for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` are 1.)

**Update**: To force the contents of `name2` to be unique within a `catalog`, use `xs:unique` as shown in the XSD below.  Then, if, say there are two `name2` elements with "Bed of Roses" content, you'll receive an error such as the following:

> [Error] catalog.xml:17:32: cvc-identity-constraint.4.1: Duplicate
>   unique value [Bed of Roses] declared for identity constraint
>   "catalog-song-name2-unique" of element "catalog".

Next question:

> 2. the elements `comments` and `genre` can be
>      optional, the rest of them are required. (I am not sure if I did it
>      in my code, please check)

Yes, because `comments` and `genre` have `minOccurs="0"` and the rest have `minOccurs="1"`.

> 3. There are just 3 types of values for the
>      element genre, pop, rock and jazz.(I am sure I did it in my code,
>      please check)

Correct.

Now, regarding the errors:

**DTDs are not compatible with XML namespaces without unnatural contortions.**

Recommend that you drop the DTD and go with just XSD.

Then, your XML without the `DOCTYPE` line and with a minor syntactical correction (delete space in `xsi:schemaLoc ation`),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog 
    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com catalog.xsd">

  <song>
    <name2>Bed of Roses</name2>
    <artist>Bon Jovi</artist>
    <album>Cross Road</album>
    <year>1995</year>
    <genre>rock</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/bon jovi</path>
  </song>
  <song>
    <name2>Fly Away from here</name2>
    <artist>Aerosmith</artist>
    <album>Just Push Play</album>
    <year>2001</year>
    <genre>rock</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/aerosmith</path>
  </song>
  <song>
    <name2>Jossie</name2>
    <artist>Blink 182</artist>
    <album>Blink 182</album>
    <year>2001</year>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/blink 182</path>
  </song>
  <song>
    <name2>Want you bad</name2>
    <artist>The Offspring</artist>
    <album>Conspiracy of One</album>
    <year>2000</year>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/the offspring</path>
  </song>
  <song>
    <name2>The One that you love</name2>
    <artist>Air Supply</artist>
    <album>The One that you love</album>
    <year>1981</year>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <comments>Good song</comments>
    <path>C://music/air supply</path>
  </song>

</catalog>
```

Will be valid against your XSD (again, with a minor syntactical correction: add a space before `type` in the declaration of `name2`):

**Update:** Now demonstrates `xs:unique` for `name2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns:w3="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="catalog">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="song" maxOccurs="5">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name2" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="artist" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="album" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="year" minOccurs="1" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="genre" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="pop"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="rock"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="jazz"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>                     
              <xs:element name="comments" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="path" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="catalog-song-name2-unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="w3:song"/>
      <xs:field xpath="w3:name2"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Ok buddy, thank you, I already dropped the .dtd but I can use the same name for two songs, the minOccurs = 1 in this case doesnt work to avoid this, I can use "Bed of Roses" twice for example.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were only concerned with the cardinality of the `name2` element.   To constrain that the value of the `name2` to not repeat, use `xs:unique`.   I've updated the XSD in the answer to show you how.

Comment: hey buddy, I am getting this error in the .xsd in www.xmlvalidation.com:                                                                      32: 39 c-general-xpath-ns: A namespace prefix in XPath expression 'w3:song' was not bound to a namespace.

Comment: I assure you that the XML included in this answer validates successfully against the XSD in this answer.   I have confirmed this both offline via Xerces-J and online at www.xmlvalidation.com, which unfortunately lacks linking facilities for me to show you simply.   Suggest that you re-check that you uploaded XML and XSD from answer and not from question.  Thanks.

Comment: Sh..t buddy, you are right. you are fu...cking awesome, thanks for your help.